# When does a polynomial have a unique real root?

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, roots

Let $p(x)$ be an arbitrary polynomial with real coefficients. Is there a convenient way to determine whether $p(x)$ has a unique real root (not counting multiplicity)?

Edit: I know about Strum's Theorem, but I was hoping that in this special case, there would be a simpler way than computing the entire sequence of Strum polynomials.

Comment: You can start with Descartes Rule of Signs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs

Comment: For polynomials of even degree, a unique real root would have to be of even multiplicity (and hence necessarily rational, if the coefficients are all rational, so you'll be able to find it).

Comment: Do you know Galois Theory?

Comment: @ Stella Biderman: I have some familiarity with it

Answer (score 1):

One obviously sufficient answer is: if it derivate is always nonnegative or nonposititive, then is must have unique real root. But this is not necessary to have unique root.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best I came up with:

If $p$ has odd degree, it has a real root $a$ so divide through by $x-a$ to the power of its multiplicity and continue as in the even case to verify there are $0$ real roots left.

Let $a_n$ be the leading coefficient of $p$. If $p$ has even degree, find the real roots $r_1,...r_k$ of $p'(x)$ and consider $p(r_1),...p(r_k)$. If they all have the same sign as $a_n$ there are no real roots, if one is $0$ and all others have the same sign as $a_n$ there is exactly one real root, otherwise there's more than one real root.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever [**Rolle's Theorem**](https://www.britannica.com/science/Rolles-theorem) can not hold such that the polynomial does not satisfy the condition *p(a)=p(b)=* 0 since *p'(x)* will have no real roots.

In this instance *a* and *b* are assumed to be roots of p(x) and this raises a contradiction if *p'(x)* has no real roots and we conclude that *p(x)* has a distinct root since none are found at *a* and *b*.

I know this may not be exactly what you were looking for but I hope it helps.